# Why is the determinant function continuous with regards to the Hilbert-Schmidt norm on matrices?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Why is the determinant function continuous with regards to the Hilbert-Schmidt norm on matrices?

I know that the determinant is polynomial of the elements of the matrix, and since $\|A\|_{HS}^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij} ^2 $ it would make sense that for 2 matrices that $\|A_1-A_2\|_{HS}$ is small enough, their determinants would be close, but I feel like I'm missing something.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you would find more under the name "Frobenius norm". Note that the determinant is multilinear in the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hilbert-Schmidt norm induces the standard topology on $\mathbb R^N \cong \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ for $N=n^2$. So all you need to check is that polynomials are continuous on $\mathbb R^N$:

1. The projections $\iota_k\colon\mathbb R^N\to\mathbb R, x\mapsto x_k$ are continuous.
2. Products $f\cdot g$ of continuous functions $f,g\colon\mathbb R^N\to\mathbb R$ are continuous.
3. Sums $f+g$ of continuous functions $f,g\colon\mathbb R^N\to\mathbb R$ are continuous.

(2. and 3. follow from $\cdot,+:\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ being continuous.)

Comment: Are there matrix norms which do not induce the standard topology?

Comment: @Roland No, all norms on $\mathbb R^N$ are equivalent.